# Javascript HashMap .size() too slow?

Tags: javascript, performance, hashmap, size

I have a HashMap and implemented a .size() method. This look like this

```
HashMap.prototype.size = function() {
var count = 0;

  for(var prop in this) {
    if(this.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      count++;
     }
  }

  return count;
};
```

The Problem is, when I would print the size with e.g console.log(map.size()) it always returns zero. But if I "wait" with an alert before then its the right value.

```
alert("STOP");
console.log(user_map.size());
```

The size of the map is about 1300 key,value pairs.

Is only the console.log() to fast and don't wait of the return value? Or what is the best method to get the size of the map?

Comment: uhm ... what does a `HashMap` in JavaScript even do? A normal, associative array (a.k.a. "an object"!) already does everything you'd want from a hash map.

Comment: I'd guess that the problem isn't with the size method, but exists elsewhere in your code. Perhaps the code that adds things to the hashmap is asynchronous and isn't completing before the code hits the console output. Are you loading the data from a URL by any chance?

Comment: As an aside, this may be faster: return Object.keys(this).length;

Comment: The data is from a json file and read with D3.js library. The asynchronous thing sounds like my problem.